# How to navigate in OpenSolaris without a mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm, opensolaris

I have a machine with OpenSolaris. After I have logged in, it seams like I have to use a mouse to start an **xterm** console (or some other application). How can I navigate in the graphical environment without a mouse? Is there any keyboard-shortcuts that I can use instead of using the mouse? I.e. I can't even access the menu without using my mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ctrl-alt-tab until you select 'top expanded edge panel' then navigate with the arrow keys.  (You may have to press the arrow a couple of times before it actually selects a dropdown menu.)  Also, if you want to use multiple virtual desktops use ctrl-alt-left/right arrow key to navigate the workspaces.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-alt-F1 should give you a login screen (terminal only).  To get back to the graphical screen it should be ctrl-alt-F8 I believe.

Comment: Thanks! I mostly means just after I have logged in, how can I navigate in the graphical environment without a mouse? I have updated my question now. However, I tested your commands, but they don't work for me.

Comment: Virtual consoles are only available/usable with latest OpenSolaris development builds and need to be enabled first. You go back to the graphical environment with ctrl-alt-f7.